# Discriminated unions with booleans in Typescript

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

To keep track of an initializing/initialized object I want to create a discriminated union with a boolean. And so I wrote the following code:

```
interface InitializingThing extends BaseThing {
    initialized: false;
    value: undefined;
}

interface InitializedThing extends BaseThing {
    initialized: true;
    value: number;
}

type Thing = InitializingThing | InitializedThing;

const thing: Thing = { initialized: false, value: undefined };
console.log(thing);

getThing().then((value: number) => {
    thing.value = value;
    thing.initialized = true;
}).then(() => {
    if (!thing.initialized) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(15 + thing.value);
});
```

(see on the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJImGYcA2wBeoA5gCoAWxyEAHpCACYDOyAQnIxOZQN4BQyA5KEzY8+CPQBcyeDg4BufoIBuuAK4RpahhBigJigL69eoSLEQp0I3AQlcQRKrQgNmbDg6d9BQjFltxKWQwKA1FX1UcDWkQNQBbACNoIxMwAE8ABxQvZABeNH9RAmJcgB9CmzF7CkdFXgQAexBGMBDaomlcgu4-Krtg2Q4AGmQomORtel19emRDRSaWxpwIADocRqIACjAOgEp6oggwL239tb3Xbe3xzWQ4pOh9-IA+ZB9BPeI1u-yx9QQCJfDprYQBapzAqhcK8QwXK4gG4vPLvT4CYAwZDbACE30cYKKgQkL3RvmQUBOaigIGBAmMviWjBW602OwAjABWZAAanaPzuhzhhyAA) )

However this gives the errors

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.(2322)
Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'.(2322)
```

I can see from hovering over the `console.log(thing)` that the type is `InitializingThing` instead of `Thing`! Which seems to be the root of the problem, but I'm not sure why the TS compiler would do this.

Comment: Why do you even have the `initialized` attribute? To check for the string being initialized, you do a typecheck, not an attribute check. Also, `true` and `false` are not types you want, and you use them like that.

Comment: I'd say that you are just holding it wrong. If you want some lazy-init scheme for your things, so that `InitializingThing` holds a info to load a proper `Thing`, all you need is a method like `load(a: InitializingThing): InitializedThing` which returns a _different instance_, because it's of a different type. Don't mutate the thing to change its type.

Comment: There are a lot of existing codebases where a single object gets mutated based on some later initialization. This example is simplified to have minimal properties, but in reality there would be a lot of changes after the initialization and capturing that in a single property makes the narrowing of the type easier.

Comment: ^ Then TypeScript will be of little help in this case. Either you embrace the type system and use it, or not. Also, mutation in general is harder to reason about. Making new instances of complex objecrs while reusing most of the data from other objects is especially easy and reasonably cheap in JS. That's where returning a new object of a different type naturally falls into place.

Comment: ford04's answer below shows that Typescript will indeed help in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code in principle works fine. However, in above example, TS actually is a bit "too smart" with its [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis). In following variable assignment

```
const thing: Thing = { initialized: false, value: undefined };
```

, the compiler narrows the type of `thing` to `InitializingThing` by interpreting its initialiser. `thing` is also assumed to keep this type, since the variable is readonly/`const`. That is why an error is triggered for the re-assignments in the `then` clause.

If you enforce `thing` to really be of type `Thing`, given sample will compile again:

```
const thing: Thing = { initialized: false, value: undefined } as Thing; // note the cast here
// or 
let thing: Thing = { initialized: false, value: undefined }; // switch to mutable `let`
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QCoAtQDmyA3sgL4BQoksiKAkiMGMHADbABehehyEAD0ggAJhjSYc+EEWIVkC5KGasOnCCIBcyeGywBueYoBu7AK4RtZ0RBigNhylXDR4SZIxXsuG3jP5CEKLi6Fh+skYKyize6lrIYFAWhorIpmwW2iBmALYARtCOFBRgAJ4ADijhyAC8HkwxajzSRAA+9V5qvi2GFAgA9iAYYAkt2tV1pNGqPvG6WAA0aeaWyNYitvYi5MiYyOH6yAD0R8gg-ZCjKAiYI7jQEBQnyP1QyE+nbBAjYGP7LbUSEoGjM4tp5hAlulMmsbHYQBpyIdnhgAO7MBC4BL9ZA5MxgOB5L7IAAGXzAJL6gww-S+ADo2P0CAAKX6EACUvQ2CDYcCgKBg1gQLEGyAI33CzPZ2gAClB+jlgFgADzZfLQAB8xXFYEl7LpvyCzOZ0NWaoKUHZtQ1JEio0IdNNgNNKUUbJkdOmsURdUSyQoZH1hpAxqtNRtclSwBgyGZAEJ3QRPSDvSIrZHUop+WAzFAQK6FJRUgMhrSIAymcyAIwAVmQAGp7R7TZyA5ygA)

Comment: Thanks! Surprising how changing it to `let` works as well.

Answer (score 2):

At this line of code, the object is invalid:

```
thing.value = value;
```

It now has the type `{initialized: false, value: number}`, which is not correct.

Instead, you need to change the values together:

```
thing = { value: value, initialized, true }
```

But to do that, you'll find that `thing` cannot be const (because you're assigning a new value to it). You'll need to make it `let`.

Comment: But `thing` does not get reassigned, only its attributes.

Comment: @9000 note the update. You can't change the attributes this way. It would create an invalid object. (But while what I originally said "works" it actually doesn't make type-sense so I deleted it.)

Comment: I agree! `InitializedThing` and `InitializingThing` are of a different ype, so they must be different instances. Also, `InitializingThing` doesn't have to declare the `.value` attribute at all, because it's, well, undefined. And the `initialized` flag is not required in any case, a type assertion / `typeof` should be used.

Comment: @9000 The code in this question is simplified to be an example. In the real code there would be many properties that are updated once `initialized` is true, and I wanted to be able to access all of them by checking one property at the beginning of the function.

Comment: I still think that a _property_ is a wrong way to frame it, you don't check a property of an object to see if it's a number or a string. The right way seems to me to be [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-4.html#type-guards) and [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).